# Set PDF text field RunDirection in pdf template using itextsharp and c#

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I'm trying to set the RunDirection on a PDF text field to RTL using C# but I didn't find how to do it.
Instead I tried to set the RunDirection to the whole page but my code doesn't work. The code I tried so far is here:

```
public static string GeneratePDF(string pdfTemplatePath, string pdfOutPutFile, Dictionary<string, object> formFieldMap, string fullPathSignature, Stopwatch stopWatch)
    {
        PdfReader reader = null;
        FileStream output = null;
        PdfStamper stamper = null;
        AcroFields formFields = null;

        try
        {
            reader = new PdfReader(pdfTemplatePath);
            output = new FileStream(pdfOutPutFile, FileMode.Create);

            stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, output);
            stamper.Writer.RunDirection = PdfWriter.RUN_DIRECTION_RTL;
            formFields = stamper.AcroFields;

            // Set Field value by Fields mapping
            foreach (var fieldName in formFieldMap.Keys)
            {
                formFields.SetField(fieldName, formFieldMap[fieldName].ToString());
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }

        stamper.FormFlattening = true;
        stamper.Close();
        reader.Close();
        output.Close();

        return pdfOutPutFile;
    }
```

Comment: RTL doesn't work that way in iText 5. You need iText 7 and the [pdfCalligraph add-on](https://itextpdf.com/itext7/pdfcalligraph) to do what you want.

Comment: I installed the NuGet Package Manager for Visual Studio.

Comment: Which NuGet package? The wrong one or the correct one? The download page on the *official web site* points to the correct package: https://developers.itextpdf.com/itext7/download-and-install-information/NET (but maybe you never visited the official web site).

Comment: I'm working with Visual Studio 2010 premium.
I installed the NuGet Package Manager for Visual Studio from Tools --> Extension Manager --> Online Gallery. 

I installed 'Common.Logging' and 'Common.Logging.Core' packages which are dependencies of iText7.
I tried but couldn't install the 'Portable.BouncyCastle' package for the following reason: 

Install-Package : The 'Portable.BouncyCastle 1.8.1.3' package requires NuGet client version '2.12' or above, but the current NuGet version is '2.8.60318.667'.

I checked, but there are no updates for NuGet client.
Any idea?

Comment: Post this as a separate question. Note that you don't need BouncyCastle, but for RTL functionality you will need the **closed source** add-on pdfCalligraph, so you might want to contact iText Software for more info.